# SolidColorBrush not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

In a C# WPF app, I have coded these pie slices: but it doesn't actually display red but a gold colour. Now I am told that this is because of Visifire has some bug. Still, is there any way I can display Red. This is important because the nurses have to know that maybe someone's allegies have not been entered.

```
if (alrg.Description == "No Allergies") 
    alrg.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
else if (alrg.Description == "Unknown") 
    alrg.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
else if (alrg.Description == "Allergies") 
    alrg.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the Color property on alrg is a Color, not a brush. 
If so, your assignment should be alrg.Color = Colors.Red;

Can you post the code for the alrg Class?

Comment: <!--<vc:DataMapping MemberName="Color"
                                    Path="Color" />-->

                   this is not working though.

Comment: [Export(typeof(IModuleViewModel))]
    class PatientAllergiesViewModel : ModuleViewModel
    {
        [Import]
        IPatientAllergiesRepository PatientAllergiesRepository { get; set; }

        static readonly String[] _groups = new String[] { "Allergies", "No Allergies", "Unknown" };

Comment: public class PatientAllergy
    {
        public PatientAllergy(String description, int count)
        {
            Description = description;
            Count = count;
        }

        public String Description { get; private set; }
        public int Count { get; private set; }
        public Brush Color { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I've tried to access the VisiFire documentation, which doesn't appear to load - perhaps it is silently timing out. If that doesn't put you off I don't know what will. If you have reason to believe this is caused by a bug in their implementation, perhaps other alternatives might be worth investigating. At the price point, Telerik would be worth a look, their documentation is vastly better and I have never known it to be unavailable.